# select query for mysqli to select all paid members from a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am storing `members name` and `id` in a table called `payments` and they pay every month so the table stores the payments like `user id` and `session id` *(session id is the month no of payment)*

I have a separate table of members details.
Now i want to fetch the list of all the members who have not paid the amount of any month less than 4th month

I have tried but its not working it is showing me the list of members who have not paid even once

```
SELECT drawid,name
FROM mem
WHERE drawid
NOT IN (SELECT  draw FROM payment WHERE inst < '4') ORDER BY drawid ASC
```

drawid and draw are same in bith the tables 
inst is referred as session id in question

Comment: Why `inst < '4'` is `inst` a `varchar` column?

Comment: yes ! it is a varcar

Comment: Try to run the inner query `SELECT  draw FROM payment WHERE inst < '4'` on mysql terminal and see what is the result ?

Comment: post your table structure and some sample data. you shouldn't be storing month number as `varchar` rather it should be `int` type.

Comment: "not paid the amount of any month less than 4th month"  does this mean not paid in any month between jan and apr?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @P.Salmon No, he might have paid for earlier month or advance but what we are checking is that if he has paid for all the months befor 4 th or not also need to get the total months he has paid for . the answer below is giving me required result but not the list of months he has paid or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT drawid, name, count(*) as numPayments
FROM mem
LEFT JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw)
GROUP BY drawid
HAVING numPayments < 4
```

Comment: i also need to find the instalments that they have paid by same query , like if the user is paid for inst 2 but not 3 or he has paid for 1 and 4 but not 2nd  . i need to get those data too . Possible ?